# Session timeout after about 1 hour in aix session

Tags: aix

we are using Aix box and we observer a session disconnection after about an hour be it normal putty connections or connections via plsql developer or any other utility.

Is there any parameter that we can change or check for this issue ?

Comment: I would like to sincerly ask the person who downgrades a question , if your have the time enough to downgrade please please try to help by providing an answer, i have looked around and havent found a solution , hence posting a question here..  we know what impact the session timouts are having for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can check TMOUT (often value 3600, I prefer 0).

```
grep TMOUT /etc/prof* $HOME/.profile
```

Comment: # grep TMOUT /etc/prof* $HOME/.profile
/etc/profile:# TMOUT=120

Comment: but i see that it is actually commented,

    # Automatic logout, include in export line if uncommented
    # TMOUT=120

Comment: You can try to set `TMOUT=0` in your .profile, but I am afraid that won't help: the timeout could also come from some infra component. Maybe login and `echo $TMOUT` to see the current setting,

Comment: the oputut of 

$ echo $TMOUT
0

Comment: your setting for TMOUT is unlimited, it must me be the network. You can check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150402/what-is-the-default-idle-timeout-for-openssh or http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keepalive

Comment: not able to find sshd_config in aix box.. also tried searching.. no results..

    # grep -i alive /etc/ssh/sshd_config                                                                       
    grep: 0652-033 Cannot open /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
    # find / -name sshd_config
    # find / -name *sshd_config*